# hostapd on two interfaces (two configuration files)

Tags: systemctl, hostapd

I have two wireless interfaces and I want to run different APs on each. (Neither hardware supports multiple SSIDs.)

I have a `.conf` file for each interface. How do I get `hostapd` to use them both automatically?

This works fine:

```
# hostapd -dd /etd/hostapd/hostapd.wlan0.conf /etc/hostapd/hostapd.wlan1.conf
```

The problem is getting it to work automatically.

One claim is to set in `/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.wlan0.conf /etc/hostapd/hostapd.wlan1.conf"
```

but this doesn't work because the whole string is interpreted as being one file -- which doesn't exist.

I see this is used by `/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service` as

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.pid -B $DAEMON_OPTS ${DAEMON_CONF}
```

However, I also see something called `/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd@.service` which does something different:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.%i.pid $DAEMON_OPTS /etc/hostapd/%i.conf
```

(what does `%i` mean?)
However, `systemctl` seems only to know about `hostapd` and not about `hostapd@`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there at the end of the question. `%i` is used for ***i**nstanced* services. Here's an excerpt of the role of instances described in the [systemd.unit(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/systemd/systemd.unit.5#DESCRIPTION):

> Unit files can be parameterized by a single argument called the
> "instance name". The unit is then constructed based on a "template
> file" which serves as the definition of multiple services or other
> units. A template unit must have a single "@" at the end of the name
> (right before the type suffix). The name of the full unit is formed by
> inserting the instance name between "@" and the unit type suffix. In
> the unit file itself, the instance parameter may be referred to using
> "%i" and other specifiers, see below.

Or in the [specifiers list](https://manpages.debian.org/systemd/systemd.unit.5#SPECIFIERS):

> ```
> ├─────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │         │               │For instantiated units this is the string between  │
> │"%i"     │Instance name  │the first "@" character and the type suffix. Empty │
> │         │               │for non-instantiated units.                        │
> ├─────────┼───────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> ```

Using instanced services will run one independent *hostapd* daemon per interface. This allows for example to alter or kill one instance with the assurance the other instance, and thus the other interface won't be affected.

You can do this for using instances:

- revert to default settings everywhere and disable and stop `hostapd.service`
- rename your configurations to accommodate an unmodified *hostapd* instanced service which expects with `%i.conf` only the interface name followed by `.conf`:

  ```
  mv -i /etd/hostapd/hostapd.wlan0.conf /etd/hostapd/wlan0.conf
  mv -i /etd/hostapd/hostapd.wlan1.conf /etd/hostapd/wlan1.conf
  ```
- use the *instanced* version of the hostapd service, distinguished by the `@` character and which is configured differently from the normal instance as already written in OP. Once per interface:

  ```
  systemctl enable --now hostapd@wlan0
  systemctl enable --now hostapd@wlan1
  ```

In the end the daemon will be running twice as these:

```
/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.wlan0.pid   /etc/hostapd/wlan0.conf
/usr/sbin/hostapd -B -P /run/hostapd.wlan1.pid   /etc/hostapd/wlan1.conf
```

(unless there was something in `$DAEMON_OPTS`).

Comment: I note that the config file name _must_ be the interface name.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited `/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service` to hard-code the two configuration files.

After editing it appears to be necessary to run

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
```

Seems like an unpleasant hack, but it works.

Comment: I believe the proper file to edit (or create) here would be **/etc/systemd/system**/hostapd.service, as the `/usr/lib/systemd/` one should be under the control of a package and your changes could be lost during an update.